# Installing PHP Mongo Driver on Windows

Tags: php, windows, mongodb, php-mongodb

I'm probably doing something silly here but I've been trying to install the mongodb php client on my windows VM running WAMP for a while and I've gotten nowhere.

I'm running WAMP 64 bit with PHP 5.4.3.  I downloaded the 1.3.2RC1 zip from [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/downloads) and I extracted the php_mongo-1.3.2RC1-5.4-vc9.dll file into wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/ext and then edited the php.ini file to include the new extension.

I restart WAMP and everything is fine, then when I try and use some of the code from the php mongo driver tutorial it says the MongoClient class cannot be found:

```
Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in C:\wamp\www\mongo\test.php ...
```

The code is simple but for completeness I'll include it:

```
<?php
    $m = new MongoClient("the-connection-string-im-using");
?>
```

Am I missing something?  Should I just be able to create a new instance of the MongoClient like above or do I need to do something else?

Cheers

James

Comment: does your ini file point to the correct dll file?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does - otherwise I would get an error when starting WAMP (which is what happened when I referenced the wrong dll).

Comment: I just did phpinfo and there's no mention of mongo in there - not sure if that's a clue...

Comment: It probably isn't pointing to it in your ini file, you should check

Comment: I'm wondering if it's in the right ini file now as there's a few.  I'll try figure it out and then post back... cheers

Comment: restart your apache and check apache error log. see if u have something suspicious there

Comment: the phpinfo output will say near the top which ini file was loaded

Comment: cheers - I got it, needed a nudge in the right direction.  Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out - I was using the wrong php.ini file.  I should have been using the one in the apache directory (C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin).

Silly.

Comment: I have enabled suitable php_mongo.dll and added the extension in both apache & php's php.ini files. Still I am getting MongoClient not found error. Please advice.

Comment: @user2003356 I would suggest opening your own question.